# WinRT - Logos with scale 100 not loading in app manifest

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

having some problems while trying to pick images with different scalings in the app manifest editor.
Following images are in the assets folder:

- Logo.png
- Logo.scale-100.png
- Logo.scale-140.png
- Logo.scale-180.png

Having "Assets/Logo.png" in "Logo" the editor detects all logo files beside the scale-100. Its saying there are logos with and without scaling qualifiers in the folder and its ignoring logos without the qualifier.

The problem is that even when trying to assign the logo.scale-100.png manually its not showing up in the "scale 100" slot.

This occurs on all images i am trying to assign. Same problem with file and folder based naming conventions.

Would be nice if someone could me point into the right direction.

Comment: Does the app show up without a logo? Isn't Logo.png the same as Logo.scale-100.png? Perhaps you could remove Logo.png?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved (thanks to filip):

Removed the Logo.png file!
VS2012 still displays "Assets/Logo.png" on the "Logo:" Field but displays the correct scale-100 image at the corresponding slot.